# Add text to post list/edit screens?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I'd like to add some descriptive text underneath the page title on both the list and edit post screens for the default post and also custom post types - e.g. "Below is a list of your recent blog posts."

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are OK with using javascript, you can try the following in your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('admin_footer', 'my_admin_footer');
function my_admin_footer()
{
    $uri = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : NULL ;

    $message = NULL;

    if ($uri AND strpos($uri,'edit.php'))
    {
        if (strpos($uri,'post_type=page'))
        {
            $message = 'My custom message for page list';
        }
        else
        {
            $message = 'My custom message for post list';
        }
    }

    elseif ($uri AND strpos($uri,'post-new.php'))
    {
        if (strpos($uri,'post_type=page'))
        {
            $message = 'My custom message for add/edit page';
        }
        else
        {
            $message = 'My custom message for add/edit post';
        }
    }

    elseif ($uri AND strpos($uri,'post.php'))
    {
        $message = 'My custom message for add/edit post or page';
    }

    if ($message)
    {
        ?><script>
            jQuery(function($)
            {
                $('<div style="margin-bottom:15px; color:#999;"></div>').text('<?php echo $message; ?>').insertAfter('#wpbody-content .wrap h2:eq(0)');
            });
        </script><?php
    }
}
```